# How do i store data from text fields in custom cells?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableview with a custom cell that gets reused several times depending on previous selection by user. Its a booking app and depending on the number of adults / children selected in previous screen, the custom cell gets reused X times.

There are 4 text fields in the cell  (Fname,Lname,Dob,Gender).

How do i store the data from each cell separately so that i can sent the data to server (I use alamofire). Like Adult1(Fname,Lname,Dob,Gender) , Adult2(Fname....)

(I am a newbie , into iOS programming)

I expect something like

a list with 4 fields   X  total number of (adults+children)

---

EDIT : (more clarification)

The table is there, the text fields are there. I want to store the data from text boxes(4 per cell) which the user types in , when the user clicks the button to leave this screen ( Next button)

Comment: Maybe you should check on [static tableview](https://manenko.com/2014/12/16/how-to-create-an-input-form-using-uitableview.html), with static tableview you can create outlet for each element in each cell.

Comment: @ocanal Eh i tried that..But there is a big issue with using static tableview , the number of cells in this tableview comes from a count taken in previous screen, WHICH a USER selects. And a user can select upto 30 . (imagine making 30 cells in a static tableview and then making functions and outlets for each item in each cell)

Comment: Implement `textFieldDidEndEditing` in the cell and use callback closures or protocol/delegate to update the data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an array of objects that can represent the data you're storing.  For example a struct as follows:

```
struct Person {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let dob: Date
    let gender: String
}
```

Then in your tableview class you can have an array of type `Person`. The index of the person in the array will correspond to what `IndexPath` they are at in the table view. In terms of when you update the array with the info is up to you. Maybe when you're finished adding all the fields to if?

Comment: Oh i see. Thank you, i will try it and if this works ,i will mark it as right answer.